# Drupal PHP block visibility rules

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks

In a Drupal block's Page Visibility Settings I'd like to prevent a certain block from showing if the second value in the path is a number. This does not seem to be working for me. Cheers.

Show block ONLY when arguments are:

domain.com/video/one (arg 0 is 'video' and arg 1 is present and NOT a number)

Don't show:

domain.com/video

domain.com/video/1

```
<?php
  if (arg(0) == 'video' && is_nan(arg(1)) && empty(arg(2))) {
    return TRUE; 
  }
  else {
    return FALSE;
  }
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? What do the argument variables contain?

Comment: Where do you use that code? Are you using it in a hook implementation, or are you using it as PHP code that decide when a module should be shown? What are you expecting the URL to be?

Comment: Apologies, this is for a block under 'page specific visibility settings'

Arguments: /video/video1 should show the block, /video/1 /video/1/... should not show the block

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is in a hook_block/hook_block_view function? You could try a different approach:

```
if (preg_match('/^video\/[0-9]+$/', $_GET['q'])) {
  // Path has matched, don't show the block. Are you sure you should be returning TRUE here?
  return TRUE; 
}
else {
  // Path has matched, go ahead and show the block  
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: The returned value should be `TRUE` when the block must be shown.

Comment: According to the original post `TRUE` should be returned when the block shouldn't be shown.

Comment: I did think that, hence my comment in the original code: "Are you sure you should be returning TRUE here?"

Comment: The third option for "Show block on specific pages" says "Show if the following PHP code returns `TRUE` (PHP-mode, experts only)." When the code returns `FALSE`, the block is not shown. That is the option the OP is using, and to which he is referring when talking of the "page specific visibility settings."

Comment: This still shows the block on /video/1 and does not show the block on /video/one

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the following code:

```
<?php
  $arg1 = arg(1);
  $arg2 = arg(2);
  // Check arg(1) is not empty, or is_numeric() returns TRUE for NULL.
  return (arg(0) == 'video' && !empty($arg1) && !is_numeric($arg1) && empty($arg2));
?>
```

As KingCrunch already said, `is_nan()` doesn't return `TRUE` when its argument is a number.
The code you reported contains another error too: `empty()` can be used only with variables, as reported in the [PHP documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

> `empty()` only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: `empty(trim($name))`.

The code I reported shows the block for paths like "video/video1"; if you want to show the block also for paths such as "video/video1/edit", then the following code should be used.

```
<?php
  $arg1 = arg(1);
  return (arg(0) == 'video' && !empty($arg1) && !is_numeric($arg1));
?>
```

Using `arg()` doesn't work if the path you are looking for is a path alias. Suppose that "video/video1" is a path alias for "node/10"; in that case `arg(0)` will return "node," and `arg(1)` will return "10." The same is true for `$_GET['q']` that will be equal to "node/10."

This happens because Drupal, during its bootstrap, initialize `$_GET['q']` with the following code:

```
  // Drupal 6.
  if (!empty($_GET['q'])) {
    $_GET['q'] = drupal_get_normal_path(trim($_GET['q'], '/'));
  }
  else {
    $_GET['q'] = drupal_get_normal_path(variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node'));
  }
```

```
  // Drupal 7.
  if (!empty($_GET['q'])) {
    $_GET['q'] = drupal_get_normal_path($_GET['q']);
  }
  else {
    $_GET['q'] = drupal_get_normal_path(variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node'));
  }
```

If you what you are checking is a path alias, then you should use the following code:

```
// Drupal 6.
$arg = explode('/', drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
return (arg[0] == 'video' && !empty($arg[1]) && !is_numeric(arg[1]) && empty($arg[2]));
```

```
// Drupal 7.
$arg = explode('/', drupal_get_path_alias();
return (arg[0] == 'video' && !empty($arg[1]) && !is_numeric(arg[1]) && empty($arg[2]));
```

Comment: I want to show the block when the second argument is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know, what your arguments looks like, but I assume you mixed up two kinds of types. `is_nan()` *only* works with numbers. If you want to test, if a value is a number,

```
var_dump(is_numeric(arg(1));
```

`is_nan()` tests, if a "numeric" value is a concrete value or "not a number" like "infinite" or the result of "0/0" or such.